# Inserting int/char into data base

Tags: c++

Inserting strings into my data base is something like this but how can I insert char or int??

```
string us,pw,sc;
cout<<"enter us: "<<endl; cin>>us;
cout<<"enter pw: "<<endl; cin>>pw;
cout<<"enter sc: "<<endl; cin>>sc;

string query="insert into users(Username,Password,Seccode) values('"+us+"','"+pw+"','"+sc"')";

const char* q = query.c_str();

qstate = mysql_query(conn,q);
```

Comment: Look into [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) and/or [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

Comment: Please sanitize user input, always !

Comment: Also use Prepared statements and you probably won't have those problems anymore. (Neither string conversion nor sanatization)

Comment: My username is `Robert\"\)\;DROP TABLE users\;--` but you can call me Bobby.

Answer (score 0):

For char, if you have variable `c` as char, you can use this to cast it to string

```
string(1, c)
```

And if you have `i` as int use this for casting

```
std::to_string(i)
```